# Use findPreference in FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

For use `getSupportFragmentManager()` I was forced to extend FragmentActivity. The problem is that before my class was a PreferenceActivity now and then gives error in all the methods of the type this.findPreference. Is there a solution? The error shows that the eclipse is The method `findPreference (String)` is undefined for the type `myClass`.

Comment: you still need to use `PreferenceActivity` if you want to show a preference screen in the lower SDK's. what are you trying to do with `Support Fragment Manager`?

Comment: I have to call a Dialog and to do so serves getSupportFragmentManager. or are there other ways to retrieve it? The dialog extends DialogFragment.

Comment: Just create the dialog without using a `DialogFragment` this is one of the rare cases where you have to do that

Comment: And what extend it instead of DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you still need to use `PreferenceActivity` for SDK's < 11 other wise you would use `PreferenceFragment`.

to show a dialog in the preference you will have to do it the old way of creating a dialog, for example

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//add everything to the builder
builder.show();
```

where ever you want to display a dialog. This is one of the very rare cases where you cannot use a `DialogFragment` and need to do it the old way